# Mysql Docker container - inserting user input on creation

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm Creating a custom docker Image based on MySQL official image.
My docker files looks like this

```
# Derived from official mysql image (our base image)
FROM mysql
# Add a database
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE company
# Add the content of the sql-scripts/ directory to your image
# All scripts in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ are automatically
# executed during container startup
COPY ./sql-scripts/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

In the folder Sql-scrips i have 2 files:
CreateTable.sql - with a create table instruction and InsertData.sql with some insert instructions.

All works fine when i create the container.

My question is :

How can i use some external variables when inserting data into the mysql. For example i have a front end interface where user can choose the name and password( php built ) and i want to insert that info into mysql database on container creation.

Comment: For example i have a front end interface where user can choose the name and password( php built ) ? you want to set from php container?

Comment: I have a main site where a user can chose an username and pass, and for each user i want to offer another app, installed on subdomain who use 2 containers(php+mysql).

Comment: you can use environment variable in sql script and pass enviroment variable at startup of your mysql container